# Reduce EF Core string discriminator column size to allow indexing

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

My EF Core discriminator column is created like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
 .HasDiscriminator<string>("MyDiscriminator")
 .HasValue<SubClass1>(nameof(SubClass1))
 .HasValue<SubClass2>(nameof(SubClass2))
  ... etc.
```

The property MyDiscriminator is not defined on MyClass - its added automatically, However the SQL table created has the column MyDisciminator defined as nvarchar(max)
The values in the discriminator column can only be from the list defined, i.e. "SubClass1", "SubClass2" etc.

If I attempt to index the discriminator column I get

```
Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Column 'MyDiscriminator' in table 'dbo.MyClass' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index.
```

Is there any way to define a string discriminator so the max length can be set to something more reasonable - and that can be indexed?

Or if not could there be any pitfalls in changing it manually in the database using something like

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyClass
   ALTER COLUMN MyDiscriminator nvarchar(50)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HasDiscriminator` configures the discriminator CLR (shadow or regular) *property* name, type and associated values. The corresponding database column name, type, constraints etc. are configured like any other property - with some of the `Property` builder overloads.

For instance, you could add the following after the code for configuring the discriminator property:

```cs
// Set discriminator column type to varchar(50)
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
    .Property("MyDiscriminator")
    .IsUnicode(false)
    .HasMaxLength(50);

// Create index 
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
    .HasIndex("MyDiscriminator")
```